# Running WordPress plugin periodically to import data

Tags: wordpress, csv, import, automation, cron

Here is the situation: I have a program producing `.csv` files with fields for title and post text (according to http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/other_notes/). I actually can modify the program's output if it's required.

I can now manually log in into WordPress admin console, go to CSV importer plug-in tab, select file and import articles contained in the file.

However, I would like to run this task automatically -- everything will be running on the server (application producing (CSV) data, application/script importing data), not remote file uploading etc ... any idea how to do it?

Comment: The bulk of the source is here: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/csv-importer/tags/0.3.6/csv_importer.php -- it looks like most of the work starts in `function post()`.  At first glance, I don't think there's going to be a trivial way to automate this -- you're either going to have to simulate a form POST via cURL (which could be complicated and error prone), or write your own version of the `post()` function that doesn't require an actual HTTP post.

Comment: How is `POST`ing via cURL error prone? Anyways, kudos for actually looking up the source ;)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into `cron` and/or WP's own [wp_schedule_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event).

Answer (score 1):

I believe [BlogSense Automation Tools](http://www.blogsense-wp.com/) provides a CSV import module that has the capability to be automated. As long as you have new csv files being generated and the titles of the posts are unique then the automation should flow.

Otherwise It will take some significant modification to the plugin; in which you would want to have it try to load a local static csv file with CURL (to replace the need to manually load one from your hard-darve) and then use the internal wordpress cronjob system to execute the process from there on out.

Here's the code I use to execute a wordpress internal cronjob every minute. You could alter the second intervals to something significantly larger.

```
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_per_min');

function add_per_min() {
    return array(
    'perminute' => array('interval' => 60, 'display' => 'Every Minute'),
    );
}

if (!wp_next_scheduled('the_name_of_my_custom_interval')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'perminute', 'the_name_of_my_custom_interval' );
}

add_action('the_name_of_my_custom_interval', 'the_function_to_run_here');
```

Comment: What happens if you don't get a visit to your site in 10 min?